# Cannot Retrieve autoincrement field from cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

I have created a sqlite database.I am displaying name,image and description from the database and binding them in listview successfully.But I cannot retrieve the **autoincrement field (cardid)** from the table.

**Here is code 1:**

```
 lvcard.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                long arg3) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  if(cursor!=null){

  if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
  cursor.moveToPosition(position);   
  String cardid = ""+cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("cardid"));
  Toast. makeText(CardList.this,"cardid--->"+cardid,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
         }
        }
});
```

**And here is the stacktrace:**

```
11-06 15:01:54.579: E/AndroidRuntime(20071): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 15:01:54.579: E/AndroidRuntime(20071): java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 3 col -1 failed
11-06 15:01:54.579: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong_native(Native Method)
11-06 15:01:54.579: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at android.database.CursorWindow.getInt(CursorWindow.java:465)
11-06 15:01:54.579: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:124)
11-06 15:01:54.579: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at com.webguru.india.ctp.CardList$1.onItemClick(CardList.java:64)
11-06 15:01:54.579: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:315)
11-06 15:01:54.579: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3570)
11-06 15:01:54.579: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1862)
11-06 15:01:54.579: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:618)
11-06 15:01:54.579: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:123)
11-06 15:01:54.579: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
11-06 15:01:54.579: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3826)
11-06 15:01:54.579: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 15:01:54.579: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
11-06 15:01:54.579: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:969)
11-06 15:01:54.579: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:727)
11-06 15:01:54.579: E/AndroidRuntime(20071):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**code 2:**
Here i removed cursor.getColumnIndex("cardid") and **inserted a columindex manually** like:

```
lvcard.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                    long arg3) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      if(cursor!=null){

      if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
      cursor.moveToPosition(position);   
      String cardid = ""+cursor.getInt(3);
      Toast. makeText(CardList.this,"cardid--->"+cardid,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
             }
            }
    });
```

But it is not returning the id **but returing a field called "cardcode".**

Here is my **sqlite data:**

[image]

and here is the **datastructure:**

[image]

Can any one please point me the mistake I am doing??

Comment: +1. Why people really love to downvote? @@

Comment: -1 why people really love to upvote .. there is no answer to such question only blind guessing, likes laato's answer(which is prolly good) because author of the question shown us a db structure but didn't show the query ...also answer can be be found in 2 min (less then writing the question) just by putting "java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 3 col -1 failed" into google search

Comment: @Selvin...but i guess I am not asking for some code and also I have done some research before posting this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Cursor` does not contain the `cardid` column and `getColumnIndex()` returns -1. Check the  projection you use when doing your query.

Comment: yeah thanks for pointing that out.Actually I was not concerned about the query since it was binding properly in the listview.I used simplecursoradapter and I had renamed cardid field to "_id".And here I tried to access the column by "cardid",hence was the error.